# Can there be a walk between a tree and it's subgraph formed by removing an edge from the tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Say *T* is a tree and *e* is an edge in *T*. *H* is a subgraph of *T* obtained by removing edge *e* in *T*. Can there be a walk in *H* that connects to *T*?

Edit: I've been trying to work it out, and what I have is that there cannot be walk that connects the two, since graph *T* is made of both graphs connected by *e*, and by removing edge *e*, subgraph *H* is formed, so both subgraph *H* and a walk connecting them can't exist.

Is this right? Is there a better way to say this if so?

Comment: What do you mean by "a walk in $H$ that connects to $T$"?

Comment: @austin so say the the two vertices for the edge _e_ are _v_ and _w_. Since _H_ is formed by removing that edge, one of the vertices has to be in T, and one has to be in _H_. So can there be a walk from _v_ to _w_?

Comment: As you have defined it, $H$ is a subgraph of $T$, so the vertices $v$ and $w$ belong to both $H$ and $T$. To answer your more specific question, there cannot be a walk from $v$ to $w$ using only edges of $H$; one characterization of trees is that there is a unique $xy$ path for any vertices $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One characterization of trees is that there is a unique $xy$-path between any two vertices $x$ and $y$. In your example, the edge $vw$ *is* the unique $vw$-path in $T$. Having removed the edge $vw$, there is now no other $vw$-path. That is to say, $v$ and $w$ belong to separate connected components. (This leads us to a second characterization of trees. They are minimally connected, meaning that the removal of any edge disconnects the tree.) Thus, a slightly stronger claim could be made: Let $x$ be any vertex in the connected component containing $v$ and $y$ be any vertex in the connected component containing $w$. There is no $xy$-path in $H$.

Comment: I see! For some reason I was thinking that by removing an edge in T that the graph would somehow split into 2 trees; but _v_ _w_ could be any edge in _T_, so _H_ wouldn't even be a tree, but a disconnected simple graph.

Comment: @user316577 Your intuition is correct; $H$ is the disjoint union of two trees. The vertex $v$ belongs to one tree and $w$ to the other, so there is no hope of walking from $v$ to $w$.